# PHP submit request not works

Tags: php

I created a register user system and seperate in two page. (registercontrol.php and register.php)

In register.php normally "Submit" button should send data to registercontrol.php but nothing happens when I click the Submit button. It's just refresh the page and do nothing, no data in members table. Am I missing something?

**register.php**

```
<?php 

require('../includes/config.php');

//if logged in redirect to members page
if ($user->is_logged_in() ){ 
    header('Location: ../dashboard/index.php'); 
    exit(); 
}

//define page title
$title = 'Demo';

//include header template
require('../layout/header.php');
?>

<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" tabindex="1" required>

<?php
    //check for any errors
    if (isset($infofn)){
       foreach ($infofn as $infofn){
            echo '<p class="p-3 text-info">'.$infofn.'</p>';
        }
    }                                   
?>

<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" tabindex="6">
```

**registercontrol.php**

```
<?php

require('../includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
    //fullname validation
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

    if (! $user->isValidFullname($fullname)){
        $infofn[] = 'Your name must be alphabetical characters';
    }   
}

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//if no errors have been created carry on
    if (!isset($infofn)){       

        try {

            //insert into database with a prepared statement
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (fullname) VALUES (:fullname)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':fullname' => $fullname
            ));
            $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');
            

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: register.php?action=joined');
            exit;

        //else catch the exception and show the error.
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a form element, with it's `action` and `method` attributes set to your other script and to be `post`. In this case `action` should be `registercontrol.php`.
Without setting the action, the form submits to itself, which in this case is the `register.php`.

Something like this should solve the issue (added only first and last line, the rest is your code):

```
<form action="registercontrol.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" tabindex="1" required>

    <?php
        //check for any errors
        if (isset($infofn)){
            foreach ($infofn as $infofn){
                echo '<p class="p-3 text-info">'.$infofn.'</p>';
            }
        }                                   
    ?>

   <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" tabindex="6">
</form>
```